# SUMIF rows equivalent in R

Tags: r

I am looking to produce summary rows in R so that a table like this:

| Region | Area | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North | AreaA | 1 | 10 |
| North | AreaB | 1 | 10 |
| South | AreaC | 1 | 10 |
| South | AreaD | 1 | 10 |

Becomes this:

| Region | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 2 | 20 |
| South | 2 | 20 |

Very simple I'm sure for someone who understands the equivalent of SUMIF (Excel) for R. I have looked at other questions but am too new to R to figure this out. Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Region = c("North", "North", "South", "South"),
  Area = c("AreaA", "AreaB", "AreaC", "AreaD"),
  Numerator = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  Denominator = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)
)

aggregate(cbind(Numerator, Denominator) ~ Region, data = df, FUN = sum)

#>   Region Numerator Denominator
#> 1  North         2          20
#> 2  South         2          20
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(across(-Area, sum))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Region Numerator Denominator
#>   <chr>      <int>       <int>
#> 1 North          2          20
#> 2 South          2          20
```

Comment: `stringsAsFactrors=FALSE` is the default unless you are using a very old version of R so it can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks, @G.Grothendieck, for having commented my answer! I am not the one who wrote `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, but `datapasta`, that pasted the data as a dataframe!